# How to merge fields into box in table on right side?

Tags: html

I have to create table similar to this 
[image: Screenshot, table overview]

so I've created following table structure in HTML

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">asd</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" rowspan="4">left box</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">asd</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">asd</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">asd</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">asd</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" rowspan="5">right box</td>
    </tr>

</tbody>
```

The structure is simplified to show only general problem. Left box is working fine, but right is not.

Demo with only left: http://jsfiddle.net/rfDms/2/

Demo with left and right: http://jsfiddle.net/rfDms/

**How to make similar table?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/AaGJ8/

```
<table width=100% border=1 class="table table-bordered">
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td>asd</td>
    <td>asd</td>
    <td>asd</td>
    <td>asd</td>
    <td>asd</td>
    <td>asd</td>
    <td>asd</td>

</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2" rowspan="4">box</td>
    <td>asd</td>
    <td>asd</td>
    <td>asd</td>
     <td colspan="2" rowspan="4">box</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>asd</td>
    <td>asd</td>
    <td>asd</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>asd</td>
    <td>asd</td>
    <td>asd</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>asd</td>
    <td>asd</td>
    <td>asd</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 1):

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/5GLSW/)**

```
<table style="width: 100%">
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" rowspan="5"></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td colspan="2" rowspan="5"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```